# How to draw a circle with stripped border in SVG?

Tags: svg

How to draw a circle with stripped border in SVG. Something like attached  image  ?

[image]

```html
<svg width="25%" height="25%" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
 
 <circle class="default" cx="25" cy="25" r="24" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
  
     <circle class="default" cx="25" cy="25" r="16" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is necessary to divide the circle with the use `stroke-dasharray` of into 8 parts

- The circumference at a radius of 20 is `2 * 3.14 * 20 = 125.6`
- Divide into 8 parts to get 4 sectors of the circle, each of which
  will have a line and a space - `125.6 / 8 = 15.7`

`stroke-dasharray="15.7, 15.7"`,  where the first value is the length of the dash the second value is a space

```html
<svg width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
 <!-- Outer circle -->
 <circle class="default" cx="25" cy="25" r="24" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
   <!-- The circle is divided into 4 sections -->
    <circle class="default" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="black" 
     stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="15.7, 15.7 "/>  
  <!--Inner circle -->  
     <circle class="default" cx="25" cy="25" r="16" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>

</svg>
```

**Update**

8 sectors

```html
<svg width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
 <!-- Outer circle -->
 <circle class="default" cx="25" cy="25" r="24" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
   <!-- The circle is divided into 4 sections -->
    <circle class="default" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="black" 
     stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="7.85"/>  
  <!--Inner circle -->  
     <circle class="default" cx="25" cy="25" r="16" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>

</svg>
```

As commented @enxaneta

> the dash height would be the stroke-width. So you may set the
>   stroke-width = radius / 5

`stroke-width="4"`

> How to make the gaps between dashes to be filled with white instead of
>   being transparent: you draw another circle with a white border and the
>   same stroke-width beneath the dashed one

Add a second circle

```
 <circle class="gold" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="gold"
         stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="7.85" />
```

I added yellow sectors you can add any other color

```html
<svg width="360" height="360" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
     
  <circle class="gold" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="gold"
      stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="7.85" /> 
  
  <circle class="black" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="black"
      stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="7.85" stroke-dashoffset="7.85"/>

</svg>
```

```html
<svg width="360" height="360" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
     
  <circle class="gold" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="gold"
      stroke-width="4" troke-dasharray="7.85" /> 
  
  <circle class="black" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="black"
      stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="7.85" stroke-dashoffset="7.85"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: @EgyEast Need more examples and a more detailed explanation?

Comment: How to make the black black dashes 8 instead of 4 ?

Comment: In a circle with radius `r = 20` the total length of the path is `2*Math.PI*20` . So if you need 8 dashes (black) and 8 gaps you need to do 2*Math.PI*20 /16 = 7.85. So use `stroke-dasharray="7.85"`

Comment: @enxaneta  Almost at the same time :)

Comment: @enxaneta Thank you for clarification. I will make changes

Comment: @enxaneta Thank you very much. Two final questions : 1) Is there a way to set the dash height to be 20% of circle radius. 2) How to make the gaps between dashes to be filled with white instead of being transparent.

Comment: the dash height would be the stroke-width. So you may set the stroke-width = radius / 5

Comment: _How to make the gaps between dashes to be filled with white instead of being transparent_: you draw another circle with a white border and the same stroke-width beneath the dashed one

Comment: @enxaneta How to make this circle to fill gaps in the first circle instead of covering it ?

Comment: @EgyEast  Now I will make an additional example on the comment of `@enxaneta`

Comment: In your markup you need to put the white border circle before the dashed one